# Why is it that $\{\vec{x}\}$ is always an orthogonal set?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is it that $\{\vec{x}\}$ is always an orthogonal set, assuming $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\vec{x}\neq 0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set $\{\vec{x}\}$ is orthogonal because for any **two distinct elements** $\vec{v},\vec{w}\in\{\vec{x}\}$, we have
$\langle \vec{v},\vec{w}\rangle=0$. (See [the Wikipedia article on vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).)

Comment: How do you know that the elements of $\vec{x}$ are distinct?

Comment: I'm talking about the elements of **the set** $\{\vec{x}\}$. That set has only one element, namely $\vec{x}$.